# WCF maxItemsInObjectGraph exceeded - how to see from svclog what objects are causing issues

Tags: c#, wcf, wcf-configuration

I am seeing the error:

> Maximum number of items that can be serialized or deserialized in an
>   object graph is '65536'. Change the object graph or increase the
>   MaxItemsInObjectGraph quota

and I understand how to address this in server and client configs via

```
<dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="262144"/>
```

in a `<behaviour>` element.

But what is really concerning me is understanding which objects are being transported that are causing the issue.  Ive upped the MaxItemsInObjectGraph  quota to 262144) and am still seeing an error with that new values exceeded.  That concerns me and I want to see in logging which objects exactly are causing such a large graph.

Ive got svclog logging set up as:

```
<system.diagnostics>
        <sources>
            <source name="System.ServiceModel"
                            switchValue="Information, ActivityTracing"
                            propagateActivity="true">
                <listeners>
                    <add name="traceListener2"
                            type="System.Diagnostics.XmlWriterTraceListener"
                            initializeData= ".\TracesGMUI.svclog" />
                </listeners>
            </source>
        </sources>
    </system.diagnostics>
```

But looking at the loggs with Service Trace View doesn't (as far as I can make out) allow me to see what objects are transported and get a handle on there byte or object graph sizes.

**Any idea how to get this info?**  Really what Im after is similar to what you see in memory viewers when you take a memory dump i.e indications of objects classes, object size in bytes and object graph size.

Comment: you can enable message logging but I doubt you get the object graph bytes sent/received.

Comment: alternatively you might implement custom `IDispatchMessageFormatter` to inspect raw messages, but you'll need to control the serialize/deserialize process manually.